# Python: open treetagger in script

Tags: python, pos-tagger

How can I use the [`treetagger`](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) in a python-script?

I have a sentence given, and the `treetagger` should analyze it. In a `normal` command line, I can do the following:

```
echo 'This is a test!' | cmd/tree-tagger-english-utf8
```

but how can I do this in a python script?

The output of the command above is the following:

```
echo 'This is a test!' | cmd/tree-tagger-english
    reading parameters ...
    tagging ...
     finished.
This    DT  this
is  VBZ be
a   DT  a
test    NN  test
!   SENT    !
```

In my script, I need the tags, i.e. "DT", "VBZ", "DT", "NN", "SENT" which I'd like to save in a list. I need these tags later to insert them in a string.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [**subprocess**](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module: a simple example follows...

```
$ cat test.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import subprocess

list_of_lists = []

process = subprocess.Popen(["cmd/tree-tagger-english-utf8"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, err) = process.communicate(sys.stdin)
count = 0
for line in output.split('\n'):
    # condition to skip the first 3 lines
    if count<3:
        count=count+1
    else:
        new_list = [elem for elem in line.split()]
        list_of_lists.append(new_list)
exit_code = process.wait()
print list_of_lists
$
```

Comment: You forgot the input. `process.communicate('This is a test')`

Comment: I've got a question: What does "/usr/bin/xargs" mean? After typing the process-line, I cannot enter any other line (it seems like python crashed...)

Comment: the xargs command is just an example. what do you mean with 'enter any other line'???

Comment: I've edited my answer to contemplate your question's context, try with your treetagger to see if it runs as you wish ;)

Comment: Hm...after typing the process-line, I get: 
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(["cmd/tree-tagger-english"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>>  reading parameters ...
 tagging ...

...is it possible to get the output directly in the script? I'd like to save the output of the treetagger in a list...

Comment: well, the output you see in terminal is just the contents of the variable `output` inside the script. You can handle the contents in any manner you neeed. now I think your problem is to understand what the script is doing.

Comment: please edit your question with the output from treetagger command in the command line so I can extend my answer to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [miotto's treetagger-python module](https://github.com/miotto/treetagger-python), which provides a very easy-to-use interface to the TreeTagger.

Just be sure to define a new `TREETAGGER` environment variable so that the Python module knows where to find the TreeTagger executables. The rest looks pretty much like this:

```
>>> from treetagger import TreeTagger
>>> tt_en = TreeTagger(encoding='utf-8', language='english')
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(tt_en.tag('Does this thing even work?'))
[[u'Does', u'VBZ', u'do'],
 [u'this', u'DT', u'this'],
 [u'thing', u'NN', u'thing'],
 [u'even', u'RB', u'even'],
 [u'work', u'VB', u'work'],
 [u'?', u'SENT', u'?']]
```

[Here is a blog post I made detailing installation and testing](https://hugonlp.wordpress.com/2015/10/07/how-to-do-pos-tagging-and-lemmatization-in-languages-other-than-english/), if you need further insructions.